# Position absolute iframe incorrect width and height

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-position

I have an iframe with the following code in the HTML:

```
<iframe id="element" src="url"></iframe>
```

I assigned this CSS rule to the iframe, and there are no other rules affecting the iframe other than a CSS reset via `normalize`.

```
#element {
  bottom: 32px;
  left: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 32px;
  top: 80px;
}
```

Ideally, this code should produce this layout:

[image]

However, the actual layout ends up like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of positioning the iframe `absolute`, you could just place it inside a container and let the container handle its `padding`. Please see the following snippet:

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  padding: 60px 20px 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#layerverse {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<iframe id="layerverse" src="https://null.perchance.org/layerverse"></iframe>
</div>
```